# Error as executing "mpirun''

Tags: command-line, 21.04, mpi

I am running to run a RegCM test simulation with the command line "mpirun -np 2 /bin/regcmMPI test_001.in" but I keep getting the error:

"mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not access
or execute an executable:

Executable: /bin/regcmMPI
Node: josh-Swift-SF314-52

while attempting to start process rank 0.

---

2 total processes failed to start"

Comment: Are you sure the executable is in the `/bin` directory not the `./bin` directory? i.e. `mpirun ./bin/regcmMPI test_001.in`

Comment: I get the same error even with that.